# CSS-Javascript : Elements added dynamically via javascript move beyond padding contraint of parent container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a vertical infinite slider to display tweets which will be sent from backend.

I have created a `div` container for the slider with `id = "tweet_space"` and for tweets I have created assigned `class = "tweet"` to them.

For the slider container I have assigned `padding:10px` in CSS file. But this padding rule is not followed at the bottom of the slider container. **Also the last elements added aren't visible in the container. The last elements; in this demo code case the numbers 49 , 50 don't appear in the slider container (You can see in developer tools that these numbers are added to slider but aren't visible).**

[image]

On clicking the button with text `click` the slider starts running.

Javascript logic I applied is:

1. Add elements to div until the last child touches the border of the
   container.
2. If the last child touches or goes beyond the border of the parent container; for every new element remove the first child and append the new element.

Code:

```js
var tweet_space = document.getElementById("tweet_space");
var tweet_space_coords = tweet_space.getBoundingClientRect();
var bottomBorder = tweet_space_coords.bottom;
var click = document.getElementById("click");
click.addEventListener("click", tweet_slider);

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


async function tweet_slider() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    var lastChild = tweet_space.lastElementChild;
    var lastChild_coords = lastChild.getBoundingClientRect();
    var tweet = document.createElement("div");
    tweet.className = "tweet";
    tweet.innerText = i;
    if (bottomBorder <= lastChild_coords.bottom) {
      var firstChild = tweet_space.firstChild;
      tweet_space.removeChild(firstChild);
    }
    tweet_space.insertBefore(tweet, lastChild.nextSibling);
    await sleep(125);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
}

#body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#tweet_space {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tweet {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Detecting Key needs</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body">

    <div>
      <button id="click">Click</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tweet_space">
      <div class="tweet">
        This is Tweet Space
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: So you want to add extra height to the container?

Comment: @ThanhTrung no I don't want to add extra height. I just want that all the elements get fitted in the slider and bottom padding constraint is also applied.

Comment: Since the height has a predefined fixed height, you should add an overflow to the container because you're sure that the sum of the height of all elements are greater than then container height

Comment: @ThanhTrung I have already added  "overflow: hidden" to the slider container. Is that what you are talking about sir?

Comment: *Also the last elements added aren't visible in the container.* --> because they are overflowing and you are hidding the overflow. What you actually have is the intended behavior, the overflwoing elements overlap the padding and are cut by the  `overflow:hidden`  that hides everything beyond the padding-box

Comment: @TemaniAfif sir how to stop overflowing elements from overlapping the padding? I want the padding constraint to be respected at bottom too. I used overflow:hidden so that new elements remain in the slider container.

Comment: Maybe you want to wrap your #tweet_space with another div, give this an overflow instead of the tweet_space

Comment: don't use padding, consider something else. Example with border: https://jsfiddle.net/z09g58x6/

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes sir will lookout ways to replace padding. As far as border option is considered last element still doesn't come into view.

Comment: it will never come to the view because there is not enough space : height of items > height of parent and the layout is from top to bottom. If you want the bottom to always show you need to change the layout to make it bottom to top and in this case the first element will be hidden

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have any idea to change this logic : height of items > height of parent ?

Comment: replace height by min-height on the parent element

Comment: @TemaniAfif sir though it is not working as I wanted but this will work too. Thank you.